# How can I present a small page sheet with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, ipad, modal-dialog, swiftui

I'm developing an app for iPad with SwiftUI.
I want to present a page sheet but with a smaller size. 
I'm using but I can't change the width of the page sheet.

```
.sheet(
    isPresented: self.$isEditing,
) {
    Text("My page sheet view")
}
```

The result is :

[image: My app page sheet]

How can I have the Apple shortcut app modal size ?

[image: Shortcut app]

Maybe it's a proprietary custom view from Apple not available with UIKit...
Thank you very much

Comment: you have `Text("My page sheet view")` in your code but its not showing in your example? Do you have any other code that you have yet to show

Comment: No, I used a navigation view in my picture. I preferred simplify the example.

Comment: Look at popovers

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can use an actionSheet (iOS 14 or earlier) / confirmationDialog (iOS 15 or later) which is much smaller or you can create your own custom-made sheet maybe with usage of [SheeKit](https://github.com/edudnyk/SheeKit).

For the case that an actionSheet / confirmationDialog is enough:

[Screenshot of the actionSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WvYv.png)

```
@State private var showingConfirm: Bool = false
@State private var actionSelection = ""
.. 

Group {
    Button(action: {
            showingConfirm.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Label("Demo")
        })
 }
// iOS 14 
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showingConfirm, content: {

        let action1 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("First action")) {
            actionSelection = "First"
        }

        let action2 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Second action")) {
            actionSelection = "Second"
        }

        return ActionSheet(title: Text("Action Sheet"), message: Text("Message"), buttons: [action1, action2])
 })

 // or for iOS 15
 .confirmationDialog("Action Sheet", isPresented: $showingConfirm, titleVisibility: .visible) {
        Button("First action") {
            actionSelection = "First"
        }

        Button("Second action") {
            actionSelection = "Second"
        }

    }
```